# Mi template en django se muestra en html no se vizualiza como debe

Tags: html, python, django, django-models, django-templates

Soy nueva en esto y Estoy realizando una agenda de contactos, ayer mi template menu funcionaba correctamente al ejecutarse, agregue la view detallespersona ejectute y de ahi fue que me mostro la template como codigo html asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi views estan asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi template:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trate de buscar mi error, incluso quite detallespersona y me sigue mostrando igual mi template asi en codigo html, les agradezco mucho todo aporte y pretendo seguir aprendiendo <3 Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función **render** toma un diccionario como tercer argumento. La solución es pasar un solo diccionario, no dos o tres como aparece en la imagen:

```
return render(request, 'principal_menu.html', {'no_personas': no_personas, 'personas': personas})
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, asi mismo me funciono